# javascript Como ejecutar función hasta que se cumpla una condición

Tags: javascript

Necesito que se ejecute una función hasta que el valor de una cookie cambie.

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function check_cookie_name(name)
    {
        var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
        if (match) {
            console.log(match[2]);
            const myArray = match[2].split("&");
            const myArray1 = myArray[myArray.length - 3 ].split("%2");
            const myArray2 = myArray1[myArray1.length - 1 ].split("%3A");
            //console.log(myArray2);
            return myArray2[1];
        }
        else{
            console.log('--something went wrong---');
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    function otracosa(){
       
      alert("valor 1");

    }


});
```

Y lo que quiero es que se ejecute continuamente la función "check_cookie_name" hasta que el valor sea 1 y entonces ejecute la funcion "otracosa"

```
valor = 0;
while (valor !== 1) {
  
   valor = check_cookie_name("micookie");
   if (valor === 1){
     otracosa();
   }

}
```

Lo que no se es donde y como implementar esta última parte para que se ejecute continuamente hasta que el valor de la cookie cambia a 1, ejecute la otra función y pare la ejecución.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Si ya sabes usar un bucle `while` por qué no lo pones dentro de tu función anónima en `document.ready(...`?? Ahí declaras las funciones que quieres, pero nunca las llamas... pues no sé, simplemente pones ahí el bucle y las llamas según sea necesario

Comment: Usar un bucle while es una muy mala idea: bloquea el hilo principal impidiendo procesar otros eventos, lo que incluye bloquear cualquier interacción con el usuario. Para hacer polling en JS se suele usar `setInterval`, pero en este caso no es necesario porque la modificación de una cookie produce un evento que se puede observar

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de ejecutarla continuamente (polling), puedes esperar a los cambios de cookies para ejecutarla sólo si realmente es necesario, usando [el API de Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged):

```
cookies.onChanged.addEventListener(() => {
  valor = check_cookie_name("micookie");
  if (valor === 1){
    otracosa();
  }
})
```

Otra opción es hacer un `polling` usando setInterval:

```
const intervalHandler = setInterval(() => {
  valor = check_cookie_name("micookie");
  if (valor === 1){
    otracosa();
    clearInterval(intervalHandler); //paramos la ejecución del check
  }
}, 300);
```

Comment: Sí esto ya lo he visto después de poner el post, el problema es que no es compatible en Safari y en IOs y necesito que en estos navegadores funcione también

Comment: Actualizado para usar un método más compatible

Answer (score 0):

Estrictamente, lo que buscas es esto:

```
var valor = 0;
while (valor !== 1) { 
   valor = check_cookie_name("micookie");
}
otracosa();
```

O, con `do while`:

```
do { 
   valor = check_cookie_name("micookie");
} while (valor !== 1);
otracosa();
```

Pero realmente no le veo sentido.